# Woocommerce - Custom link in product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I am new in both `WordPress` and `Woocommerce`. While creating an E-commerce website using `WordPress` and `Woocommerce`, I do not know how to remove the link (in the red rectangle).

I do not know how people call the link, so sorry for this inconvenience.

[image: product]

If you know, please let me know how to remove it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the breadcrumbs from Woocommerce, add the following to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
function jk_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
}
```

If you only want to remove them from the single product page, change this to:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_wc_breadcrumbs_single' );
function remove_wc_breadcrumbs_single(){  
    if (is_single()) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both but none of those work. I am using Divi Theme. Do you have other ways to solve it? Thank you